# DAViCal and nginx: problem with HTTP method REPORT

Tags: nginx, webdav, http-method

I found this problem trying to switch from lighttpd to nginx: my webserver hosts DAViCal for addresses and contacts, but in order to work it needs support for some uncommon HTTP methods on the web server. These are `PROPFIND`, `OPTIONS`, and `REPORT`.
Looking around I found the nginx does not provide any of them but the first two are supporte by an extension called [http-dav-ext](https://github.com/arut/nginx-dav-ext-module/).
I am still missing the `REPORT` method.